# Reading a CSV file with headers having double quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have .csv file with the header row as

`VM,Mac Address,Type,"IP Address"`

With the following code I can print the value of `VM` but not `IP Address`. If remove the `""` surrounding `IP Address` it works.

```
CSV.foreach(vcenter_vnetwork_file, headers: true, :quote_char => "\x00") do |row|
    puts row['VM']
    puts row['IP Address']
end
```

I tried using `puts row['\"IP Address\"']` but this did not work. I can programmatically remove those `""` from the header row but is there any way to get this working woring without any workaround? I also tried adding `:force_quotes => true` in the `CSV.foreach`  loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you set the `:quote_char` to be `"\x00"`? Set it to *a quote indeed*.

```
CSV.foreach('/tmp/qqq.csv', headers: true, :quote_char => '"') do |row|
  puts row['IP Address']
end
```

Comment: what does `"\x00"` mean? looks like some hexadecimal code for some cahracter. Can we have 2 characters set as `quote_char ` ?

Comment: You never need `"\x00"`. It’s a hexadecimal for c-string terminator, literally having `0` ASCII code. You’ll encounter issues with it much earlier: `CSV` will _stop reading file on it_, since it doesn’t use binary mode while reading a file.